# Cannot compile with texliveonfly

Tags: compiling

I installed TeX Live 2019 on Windows 10 and added `texliveonfly` to TeXworks. Python is also installed. The problems are:

1. If I input `texliveonfly filename.tex` on `cmd`, then it returns:

   > texliveonfly.py: error: texliveonfly.py: It appears tlmgr is not installed.  Are you sure you have TeX Live 2010 or later?
   >
   > C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:907: command failed with exit code 2:
   >
   > python.exe c:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\texliveonfly\texliveonfly.py rie geo.tex
2. If I compile a `.tex` file using `texliveonfly` (on TeXworks), then I get:

   > C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:927: C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:894: program not found (not part of TeX Live): python.exe

Comment: Change `"tlmgr"` in the line 342 in the texliveonfly.py to
`"tlmgr.bat"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works perfectly. As I install texliveonfly via tlmgr, perhaps someone should fix this typo in the online resource for others' convenience.

Comment: That is not a typo. The other platforms than Windows require
the original code. A conditional code can be written by using
a function `platform.system()`. I'll ask the author a correction
if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Can I suggest posting your first comment as an answer? It would help with discoverability of the solution, and I will be able to upvote it, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of Windows, change

```
tlmgr
```

in the line 342 in the texliveonfly.py to

```
tlmgr.bat
```

Platform independent change of texliveonfly.py is possible
and I asked the author to change the script.

Comment: Sadly, your proposed changes did not land in the 2022 release either...

Answer (score 2):

> Couldn't leave a comment since I do not have enough reputation.

In texlive 2022 + Windows 10, I ran into issues running texliveonfly as well. Posting my solution here in case it helps someone else.

I got hold of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maphy-psd/texliveonfly/master/texliveonfly.py since texliveonfly I obtained from tlmgr was an exe file.

I ran into the OP's issue as well as an issue with path as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898620/typeerror-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-none-type.

Consequently, I had to make two changes: 1) Akira's suggestion to line 342, and   2) update os.getenv('HOME) to os.getenv('HOME', "not found")
.

Comment: This answer is great! For the completeness, how to proceed: 1) rename texliveonfly.exe in texliveroot\bin\win32, 2) put texliveonfly.py there, 3) add texliveonfly.bat file there with the one-line contents "py %~dp0texliveonfly.py %*". Also, it looks like line 342 is fixed in the source now!